# Set control property value via a string variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, properties, controls

I am very new to vb.net and the finding the terminology/concepts a little daunting at the moment, so forgive the newbieness of this question.

I'm wanting to set some control properties via variables. For instance:

```
Dim f As DateTimePicker
Dim g As String = "Short"
f.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.g
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set it the system short format, you would just do it like this:

```
Dim f As New DateTimePicker
f.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
```

Your idea was correct, but [the `Format` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts an enumerated value which are [predefined `Enum` values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepickerformat(v=vs.110).aspx). Without going into reflection (which is a more advanced topic) you need to use a predefined value instead of trying to set it dynamically with a string value.

**Edit**

If you really want to use a string value to set the `Format`, you can do it this way:

```
Dim f As New DateTimePicker

' This must be set to a valid DateTimePickerFormat name.
Dim formatType As String = "Short"

f.Format = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(DateTimePickerFormat), formatType), DateTimePickerFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, Reflection is the way to do this dynamically? Looks like I'll be sticking to multi-line ifs for the time-being if it's advanced..

Comment: @stigzler - I updated the answer to show how you can set it using a string value.